# docker-compose with Spring Boot and MySQL integration keeps occurs error Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker-compose

I am about to finish my spring boot project.

However, the deployment with docker-compose is just painfully not working

Below is my codes

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  ibin-db:
    container_name: ibin-db
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: iBinApiDB
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  ibin-inplay:
    image: openjdk:14
    volumes:
      - ./run.sh:/home/ibin/run.sh
      - ./ibin-inplay/build/libs:/home/ibin/libs
    ports:
      - 8001:8080
      - 16100:16100
    networks:
      vpcbr:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.219.69
    depends_on:
      - ibin-db
    command: bash -c "cd /home/ibin && sh run.sh"

  networks:
      vpcbr:
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
          config:
            - subnet: 192.168.219.0/24
```

application.yml

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://ibin-db:3306/iBinApiDB?useSSL=false
        username: root
        password: root
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        generate-ddl: true
```

didn't miss to run ./gradlew bootJar

However, error pops up no matter what.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

please help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two containers aren't on the same Docker-internal network, so they can't see each other.  The `ibin-inplay` container is explicitly assigned to the `vpcbr` network; the `ibin-db` container doesn't have any manual `networks:` configuration, so Compose assigns it to a `default` network.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes what Compose will automatically create for you.

You shouldn't need to manually assign IP address to containers or otherwise do manual network configuration in Docker.  I'd recommend deleting all of the `networks:` blocks in the whole file (both the top-level block and the one for the `ibin-inplay` container) and using the `default` network everywhere.